# слова исключения при проверке через regexp

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть метод проверки через регулярки на плохие слова заменяя их ***

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(temp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
m.replaceAll("***");
```

Подскажите как сделать слова исключения например "три рубля" будут заменены на "три ру***" а надо его пропустить при проверке ?

Comment: Используйте границы слова: `Pattern.compile("\\b" + temp + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);`

Comment: я пробовал  но в temp  у меня слова строкой перечисленные через знак '|'. получается \\b в начале строки и в конце \\b. А надо чтоб сравнивал с каждым словом в строке учитывая \\b

Comment: если отдельно подставлять в виде \\bслово\\b то работает

Comment: `"\\b(?:" + temp + ")\\b"`

Comment: работает!!! спасибо

Comment: а как можно добавить повторение, если два или больше слов без пробелов напишут ?

Comment: `"\\b(" + temp + ")(?:\\s*\\1)*\\b"`?

Comment: супер!! благордарю )))) я уже голову сломал себе с регулярками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в `temp` находится шаблон типа `плохое_слово_1|плохое_слово_2`, необходимо заключить это выражение в круглые скобки (подмаску) и с обеих сторон добавить по границе слова `\b`: `"\\b(" + temp + ")\\b"`.

Если нужно также добавить в совпадение повторы того же слова, которые находятся сразу после найденного слова, нужно добавить `(?:\\s*\\1)*` перед последней границе слова:

```java
"\\b(" + temp + ")(?:\\s*\\1)*\\b"
```

См. [пример](https://regex101.com/r/3PMRRU/1/).

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(...|...)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1, одно из перечисленных через `|` слов
- `(?:\s*\1)*` - ноль и более повторов 0+ пробельных символов, за которыми следует то же слово, которое было захвачено в первую подмаску
- `\b` - граница слова

**Если нужен повтор не того же самого слова, а любого слова из заданных в подмаске**, используйте

```java
"\\b(?:" + temp + ")(?:\\s*(?:" + temp + "))*\\b"
```

Comment: уже протестил, остается косяк если друг за другом разные слова из шаблона

Comment: @DMITRIYBLAZHKO Это не "косяк". Если нужен повтор не того же самого слова, а любого слова из заданных в подмаске, используйте `"\\b(?:" + temp + ")(?:\\s*(?:" + temp + "))*\\b"`

Comment: подскажи, есть какая нибудь статья или кинга в которой подробно все прочесть про регулярки можно ? или это на собственном опыте знания накапливаются ?

Comment: @DMITRIYBLAZHKO В моём случае на собственном опыте. В [моём профиле на англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew?tab=profile) написано "Visited 2158 days, 2149 consecutive". И всё это время меня интересовали только регулярные выражения. Можете почитать "Mastering Regular Expressions" Джеффри Фридла (легко гуглится, кстати).

Comment: понял, прочту обязательно